# Extract html tags and div class from a variable containg the HTML of external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extract

this code gets the HTML of an external URL and passes it to the variable: text, then alerts the page with the html contained in the variable. I need to separate elements from the variable.

document.getelement only works with html in the current page. is there another method

### i.e text.document.getelementbyid('MyDiv')

```
test script<script type="text/javascript">
var your_url = 'http://google.com;

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jquery.xdomainajax.js  ------ from padolsey

jQuery.ajax = (function(_ajax){

var protocol = location.protocol,
    hostname = location.hostname,
    exRegex = RegExp(protocol + '//' + hostname),
    YQL = 'http' + (/^https/.test (protocol)?'s':'' + '://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?      callback=?',
    query = 'select * from html where url="{URL}" and xpath="*"';

function isExternal(url) {
    return !exRegex.test(url) && /:\/\//.test(url);
}

return function(o) {

    var url = o.url;

    if ( /get/i.test(o.type) && !/json/i.test(o.dataType) && isExternal(url) ) {

        // Manipulate options so that JSONP-x request is made to YQL

        o.url = YQL;
        o.dataType = 'json';

        o.data = {
            q: query.replace(
                '{URL}',
                url + (o.data ?
                    (/\?/.test(url) ? '&' : '?') + jQuery.param(o.data)
                : '')
            ),
            format: 'xml'
        };

        // Since it's a JSONP request
        // complete === success
        if (!o.success && o.complete) {
            o.success = o.complete;
            delete o.complete;
        }

        o.success = (function(_success){
            return function(data) {

                if (_success) {
                    // Fake XHR callback.
                    _success.call(this, {
                        responseText: data.results[0]
                            // YQL screws with <script>s
                            // Get rid of them
                            .replace(/<script[^>]+?\/>|<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi, '')
                    }, 'success');
                }

            };
        })(o.success);

    }

    return _ajax.apply(this, arguments);

 };

})(jQuery.ajax);



$.ajax({
url: your_url,
type: 'GET',
success: function(res) {
    var text = res.responseText;
    // then you can manipulate your text as you wish
    alert(text);
}
});
})(jQuery.ajax);

$.ajax({ url: your_url, type: 'GET', success: 
function(res) { var text = res.responseText; 
// then you can manipulate your text as you wish  
alert(text); } });
```

Comment: can wrap any valid html string in `$()` using jQuery and use jQuery methods on it. It does not have to be in the DOM

Comment: I'm not sure if I have seen you exact point but I think `res.responseText` at the end of your code is the html string of your external page, and you want to find a specific element in it. am I right?

Comment: yes, the text variable returns the who html of the external page but I want to extract div's

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DOM element and add the variable `text` to it and manipulate that way.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = text;
document.getElementbyId('MyDiv');
```

Or with jQuery:

```
var el = $('<div></div>');
el.html(text);
$('#MyDiv', el);
```

Comment: I can't get this working in jquery or jscript: var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.innerHTML=text;
    el.getElementById('bk62');****************this line doesn't work, causes script to stop running
    alert('test '+ el);

Comment: I can't get this working in jquery or javascript, this is what i am using;